# Unexplainable forced scroll down in RecyclerView after notifyItemMoved() is called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a list of items implemented with RecyclerView. Under certain conditions items might be moved to the very end of the list and I need that to be animated. So first I move the items to the end in the data source (ArrayList in my case) and call adapter's `notifyItemMoved(oldPosition, dataSet.size() - 1)` method. Everything works ok except the case when the element I move to the end (it doesn't actually matter if it's the very end of the list or just a bit lower position) is either the very top in the list or the very first **partly visible**. In such cases not only moved item is animated but entire list scrolls down with it.

I thought it might be some kind of a mess in my code so I created a clean test application with a RecyclerView component and the result was the same.

I think it's a bug of `RecyclerView` because it's still very green component and Goggle continues to develop it, although I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one who faced such a problem so I hope somebody has a workaround for that.

Here's code snippets of my `Activity`, `RecyclerView.Adapter` and a layout.

**Activity**

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new    SimpleDividerItemDecoration(RecyclerViewActivity.this));
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataSet;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;

        mDataSet = new ArrayList<String>();
        mDataSet.add("San Francisco");
        mDataSet.add("Los Angeles");
        mDataSet.add("Seattle");
        mDataSet.add("Portland");
        mDataSet.add("Sacramento");
        mDataSet.add("San Diego");
        mDataSet.add("Chicago");
        mDataSet.add("Boston");
        mDataSet.add("New York");
        mDataSet.add("New Jersey");
        mDataSet.add("Washington");
        mDataSet.add("Miami");
        mDataSet.add("New Orlean");
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                String item = mDataSet.get(itemPosition);
                mDataSet.remove(itemPosition);
                mDataSet.add(item);
                notifyItemMoved(itemPosition, mDataSet.size() - 1);

            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemName.setText(mDataSet.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView itemName;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_item_text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's a video of how it looks:
https://youtu.be/kjG4oFE7o0w

1) Portland - ok.

2) Seattle - ok.

3) Los Angleles - ok.

4) San Francisco - NOT OK - entire list is scrolling down with the item.

And further in the video can see examples of the same behavior with the elements which aren't at the top of the list but are the very top visible ones and partly hovered by the list's top border.

Comment: It's an android bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=99047

Comment: Hey bro, did you solved this problem?

Comment: @bill good question :-) got the same problem!

Comment: @silly Finally I use the "scrollToPosition(0)" way to temporary solve the problem.

Comment: @Bill No, I didn't find any decent solution. What was your way of fixing?

Comment: @Alexandr As you can see the "Issue Tracker" link below, this is an android bug and not fix yet. So I just use the temporary solution way: "scrollToPosition(0)" as recommend. -_-|||

Answer (score 2):

My temporary solution:

```
// mLayoutManager is LinearLayoutManager from RecyclerView
int visible = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int offset = mLayoutManager.getChildAt(visible).getTop();

... remove, add and call notifyItemMoved

mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(visible, offset);
```