# notifyItemMoved animation feature

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I move only first visible item to the end of the list by method(notifyItemMoved), adapter scrolls to the end, how can I disable this scrolling? Everything works fine with other position expect only first visible position.

Comment: Try using [RecyclerView#scrollToPosition(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)), I don't know how this will look like.

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [Unexplaniable forced scroll down in recyclerview after notifyitemmoved is call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697939/unexplainable-forced-scroll-down-in-recyclerview-after-notifyitemmoved-is-call). However, the whole behavior refers to a RecyclerView bug at google, which was marked as "Won't fix: intended behavior". So, the only fix is a workaround one.